# Creating virtual server with private networking only on dedicated host

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a virtual node on one of our dedicated nodes with only private networking enabled. Using terraform (support for dedicated hosts) it gives me an API error as follows:

> softlayer_virtual_guest.vsi: Error generating order template: SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound: Unable to find Uplink Port Speeds at 100 Mbps. (HTTP 200)

Aboves error is produced when private_network_only is set to true, setting it to false actually brings the node up (but with public interface enabled).

I have tried adding VS manually through panel, when selecting network it only shows options with public and private networking. Due to this, my question would be: is it possible to have VS node on dedicated nodes with only private networking enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable private networking with the private_network_only flag, but unfortunately there is an issue here, the ordered instance has public and private network no matter if you selected private only. This was reported and it will be fixed as soon as possible, I will let you know when it is done through this page.

On the other hand, the error you got is because you didn't specify the network_speed value which is required for instances with public or private network.

Basically you need to add following values on your order (using terraform):

```
public_network_speed = 100
private_network_only = true
```

OR

```
network_speed = 100
private_network_only = true
```

References:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/softlayer/r/virtual_guest.html

Comment: I reviewed carefully this behavior and I noticed that there is an issue, I updated my answer. Sorry for any inconvenience.